# Why am I not able to focus on this menu item when using tab and arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have menu options like below:

```
<li class="item1" role="menuitem" tabIndex="-1">
  <svg>...</svg>
  <span>Item #1</span>
</li>

<li class="item2" role="menuitem" tabIndex="-1">
  <svg>...</svg>
  <span>Item #2</span>
</li>

<li class="item3" role="menuitem" tabIndex="-1">
  <svg>...</svg>
  <span>Item #3</span>
</li>

<li class="item4" role="menuitem" tabIndex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
  <svg>...</svg>
  <span>Item #4</span>
</li>
```

From everything that I've read about `aria-disabled`, it seems like it should still allow the user to reach the element via tab and arrow keys (that the element is still focusable). However, when I try to navigate to the fourth menu item via tabs and arrow keys, it doesn't focus on it and it skips it entirely instead. I tried removing the `aria-disabled` just to see if that would change anything and that made it reachable via the keyboard. I can navigate fine through the rest of the menu items, but for some reason I can't reach the fourth...

Comment: Which browser are you in? I'm not able to focus any of these with keyboard because of tabIndex="-1". Edit: in Chrome

Comment: I am in Chrome also! Yeah, I was also confused about how I was able to tab through them even though the value for `tabIndex` was -1...

Comment: Maybe what's inside the `<li>` matter. Can you show the relevant HTML? Even better, as a snippet

Comment: @ITgoldman It's just an svg (an icon) and the menu option name inside of each of these; they seem ok to me, nothing that looks obviously wrong..I edited my question above!

Comment: Do you have a specific assistive technology enabled for testing? Which one? (But also, why are you applying `tabindex="-1"` if you want them to be focusable?)

Comment: Hm, I'll need to keep digging on my end I think..need to figure out why -1 works in my application; I will post updates here if I find any!

Comment: Does anyone know if `aria-disabled` elements are focusable? I've been seeing some posts say that not being able to tab through disabled elements is expected and others that suggest disabled elements are still tabbable

Comment: Are you sure that menuitem is the right role? It suggests that the element is and works like a menu item. In particular, menu items are normally working in focus/form mode and are navigated with arrow keys, not tab. Except if you are really implementing a true popup menu behaving like that, you should probably not use it.

Comment: Disabled elements are normally not focusable, but aria-disabled don't really disables anything. It's just an indication telling screen reader users that the element is disabled, but  it doesn't do anything in itself, and so per se it stays focusable. However it may be confusing to still focus an element said to be disabled, so you need to be very careful with this.

Comment: ARIA attributes have **absolutely no effect** on keyboard use. They are strictly hints to assistive tech (such as a screen reader) to convey semantics. If you use the `disabled` property on an `<input>`, **that** affects the keyboard. But if you have a custom component and want to disable it, you'd probably apply styling and prevent keyboard focus but assistive technology doesn't know anything about your styling and will not know the element is disabled unless you add `aria-disabled="true'`. https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#nativesemantics - "*Adding ARIA...does not change the behavior*"

Comment: I believe we are missing a critical part of othe issue: The Javascript library used. Can you please share that, @user18971245? Neither does `tabindex="-1"` allow a user agent to focus the element on behalf of the user, nor do browsers or screen readers (afaik) set focus by using arrow keys. Javascript needs to implement that, and the library you are using is probably interpreting `aria-disabled` not correctly. You’d need to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't focus for me if `tabindex=-1`. If you want to make an element focusable just add `tabindex=0` to it. Read more on [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<button>focus me</button> then click [tab]
<ul>
  <li class="item1" role="menuitem" tabIndex="0">
    <svg width="50" height="50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /></svg>
    <span>Item #1</span>
  </li>

  <li class="item2" role="menuitem" tabIndex="-1">
    <svg width="50" height="50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="red" /></svg>
    <span>Item #2 with tabindex=-1</span>
  </li>

  <li class="item3" role="menuitem" tabIndex="0">
    <svg width="50" height="50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /></svg>
    <span>Item #3</span>
  </li>

  <li class="item4" role="menuitem" tabIndex="0" aria-disabled="true">
    <svg width="50" height="50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" /></svg>
    <span>Item #4</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>focus me</button>
```

Comment: thanks, since it works on here and not in my project, I think I need to dig a bit more..